# How to identify the chosen selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#select_id1, #select_id2, #select_id3').change(function() {
    // If '#select_id1' has changed, 'str' should be equal to 'select_id1'.
    // If '#select_id2' has changed, 'str' should be equal to 'select_id2'.
    // If '#select_id3' has changed, 'str' should be equal to 'select_id3'.
    str = <what should be here ?>
});
```

Comment: If you want the selector with which the change handler was added, then you have to do more work. One example would be if the select element can be selected using criteria's other than id - `$(".select1, #select2, div > .select3")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the id of the element that invoked the change by `this.id`.

```
$('#select_id1, #select_id2, #select_id3').change(function() {
    str = this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or (less efficiently):

```
$('#select_id1, #select_id2, #select_id3').change(function() {
  str = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

But basically `this` is set to the element on which the event took place.

Comment: There really is no reason to use this - using jQuery when directly getting the DOM attribute directly is possible is massively inefficient and should be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

For the more general case, where not only IDs are used, as suggested by @Anurag, you can do the following:

```
// Save the selector
var selector = ".someClass, #someId, tr.someTrClass";

$(selector).change(function () {
    var selectors = selector.split(","),
        matching = []; // Remember that each element can
                       // match more than one selector
    for (var i = 0, s; s = selectors[i]; i++) {
        if ($(this).is(s)) matching.push(s);
    }

    str = matching.join(","); // Your list of all matching selectors
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either look at `this.id` directly or indirectly via a passed in event object:

```
$('#select_id1, #select_id2, #select_id3').change(function (e) {
    alert(e.target.id + ' == ' + this.id + ' ... ' + (e.target.id == this.id));
});
```

Most people just look at `this` but there are times when you might be interested in more than just the target of your event.